# How do I get the XML format of Bugzilla given a bug ID using python and XML-RPC?

Tags: python, scripting, xml-rpc, bugzilla

**This question has been updated**

I am writing a python script using the python-bugzilla 1.1.0 pypi. I am able to get all the bug IDs but I want to know if there is a way for me to access each bug's XML page? Here is the code I have so far:

```
bz = bugzilla.Bugzilla(url='https://bugzilla.mycompany.com/xmlrpc.cgi')
try:
   bz.login('name@email.com', 'password');
   print'Authorization cookie received.'
except bugzilla.BugzillaError:
   print(str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
   sys.exit(1)

#getting all the bug ID's and displaying them
bugs = bz.query(bz.build_query(assigned_to="your-bugzilla-account"))
for bug in bugs:
    print bug.id
```

I don't know how to access each bug's XML page and not sure if it is even possible to do so. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the XML page? Maybe you should describe this, because otherwiese you can do a bug.__dict__ instead of bug.id and you will see the information stored in the bug.

Comment: @Sven Could you please elaborate on what bug.__dict__ does? I am trying to access the XML page because I can't get attributes such as comments, dupe_of, QA and assignee's name when I'm trying to access them using xml-rpc

Comment: Ok, bug.__dict__ can show you some internal defined things which can be accessed. for e.g. bug.assigned_to will give you the assigned person  and bug.depends_on the dependencies. Using the XML directly is not neccessary, but for the whiteboard things there must be an extra option it is omitted by default. But I have no example for the moment. Maybe looging to the bug.py or the base.py in the plugins diretory.

Answer (score 0):

```
bz.getbugs()
```

Will get all bugs, `bz.getbugssimple` is also worth a look.

Comment: For both of those methods, I need to pass a list of bug IDs as parameters. I want to know if I can query for all bug IDs

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import bugzilla

bz = bugzilla.Bugzilla(url='https://bugzilla.company.com/xmlrpc.cgi')
bz.login('username@company.com', 'password')

results = bz.query(bz.url_to_query(queryUrl))

bids = []

for b in results:
   bids.append(b.id)

print bids
```